# Make The Folder Name The Same As The File Names

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, rename, batch-rename

I have a directory structure as below:

```
Folder
    > FileName1.abc
    > Filename2.abc
    > .............

Folder2
    > FileName11.abc
    > Filename12.abc
    > ..............

> ..........
```

etc. I have a command that can prepend folder names to filenames.

**Sample:**

```
Folder1_Filename1.abc
Folder1_Filename2.abc
```

I want to change it like this.

**Make the folder name the same as the file names:**

```
Folder1.abc
Folder1 (1).abc
Folder2.xyz
Folder2 (1).xyz
```

i.e. As a result I want to replace the filenames with the folder name.
If there are files with different names with the same extension, they can add (1), (2) to the end of the names.

**Script:**

---

```
@echo off
pushd "Folder"
for /d %%D in (*) do (
  pushd "%%D"
  for /r %%F in (*) do (
    for %%P in ("%%F\..") do (
      ren "%%F" "%%~nxP_%%~nxF"
    )
  )
  popd
)
popd
```

---

The above command doesn't do what I want.

This command just adds the folder name to the beginning of the filenames.

---

**PS:** I changed the command `"%%~nxP_%%~nxF"` to `"%%~nxP%%~xF"` command.
And I have almost completed what I wanted.
But at one point I saw that only 1 of the files with the same extension changed their name.
I've been looking for a command that can add (1), (2), (3) when saving the names of files with the same extension; but I couldn't find it.

**Detailed example:**

---

```
Folder
    > Folder.jpg
    > Folder (1).jpg
    > Folder (2).jpg
    > .............
```

---

I would be grateful if you know of a command that can do what I want other than the above command.

You deserve appreciation.

Comment: Please edit your samples to match the structure shown in the initail one. Your sample desired result currently looks like 4 files, 2 pairs of identically-named files (which is impossible), in a single directory.

Comment: Why not **PowerShell**?

Comment: It doesn't have to be CMD.
It could be in Powershell.

Examples are just an example.
There are hundreds of folders and hundreds of files.
But some folders have files with different names with the same extension.

The code in the topic is just an example; There may be different codes as I wrote in the note.

Just I want this: 

Change name; if there is a file with the same extension, change the name; but add (1) to the end.
If there are more files, INCREASES (1) by 1.

Comment: You talk about numerical suffixes but don't show any in your example! Why do you have two files named `SubFolder1.abc` (still in `SubFolder1`???), not `SubFolder1.abc` and `SubFolder1 (1).abc` which is what ( I think ) you are describing?  It's confusing.  Also. what are you referring to when you say "There may be different codes"? Does it matter which file is assigned which number?

Comment: Updated the question to clear up any misunderstandings.
I'm using the script in the question to do what I want.
However, I cannot do exactly what I want.
That's why I wanted to express that if there are people who have another script that can do what I want, they can share them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near as I can tell, this is what you want.

In the posted code, the [`Rename-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1) statements include the `-WhatIf` parameter, so it can be safely run to produce sample results, but not acutally perform the action. If the sample output is the desired output, remove the `-WhatIf` parameter from both `Rename-Item` statements and re-run the code.

For multiple files with the same extension, the code is simpler with adding numerical suffixes to all the files, starting the numbering with `0`. This allows a single statement/pattern to be applied to all the files.

Edit the `$TopFolder` assignemnt statement to reflect a valid path before executing.

```
$TopFolder    = '<Path to "Folder">'
Get-ChildItem $TopFolder -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File | Group-Object Extension | ForEach-Object{
        If ( $_.Count -eq 1 )
        {
            $_.Group[0] | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name + $_.Extension} -WhatIf
        }
        Else
        {
            $NameTemplate = $_.Group[0].Directory.Name + ' ({0})' + $_.Name
            For ( $i = 0 ; $i -lt $_.Count ; $i++ ) {
                $_.Group[$i] | Rename-Item -NewName ( $NameTemplate -f $i ) -WhatIf
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[ForEach-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1)

[For Loop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.1)

[Group-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1)

[-f Format Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f)

Comment: I run the code; but it didn't work.

As you indicated, I changed the relevant part to: `$TopFolder = '<D:\Life>'`

And I run it on powershell; but it didn't work.
I couldn't figure out if there is something I'm not doing right or if there is an error in the code.

Comment: You don't need the  `<` and `>` characters. They're not part of the string. You want `$TopFolder = 'D:\Life'`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I overlooked removing the `-WhatIf` parameter. Now worked.
I wonder if you have the opportunity to help with the [Other](https://superuser.com/questions/1681541/how-can-i-automatically-download-web-pages-for-offline-viewing) issue I shared?